How to use vector's vrl language to consume data like [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":12},{"z":83}] from Kafka? {"a":1} is a complete data
How to use vector's vrl language to consume data like
[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":12},{"z":83}] from Kafka?
{"a":1} is a complete data
Tried this method, but failed:
[transforms.parse_array]
type = "remap"
inputs = ["kafka"]
source = ‘’‘
    if !.event.is_array() {
        .drop_event = true;
    } else {
        .events = array::map(.event, |item| { root = item; });
    }

